# How to migrate changes in MDS across environments (Dev, Stg, Prd)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, master-data-services, master-data-management

We've started using MDF inhouse recently. So far, we've had a single person work on MDS at a time. This allows that person to work on a single ticket at a time, once they're done migrating all of MDS with or without data to STG, and if it passes testing gets promoted to PRD.

As of this week, we're two programmers working on MDS. The concern is that if a developer wants to promote their changes from DEV to STG, then they have to migrate all of MDS. If the second developer is halfway through development then their changes will be migrated too.

Is there a way to promote just certain parts of the code? And how do you handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called Simultaneous versions in MDS. You can try to fit in to your organizations for multiple developers to work on MDS at the same time.

[Simultaneous Versions in MDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/versions-master-data-services?view=sql-server-2017#sequential-or-simultaneous-versions)

Answer (score 0):

To do this we use the ModelPackage editor to modify the pkg to only include the entities, business rules and views that need to be migrated without including other in-flight work from the other developer. You can find it on the server with the following path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Master Data Services\Configuration>